# How to manage python dependencies based upon user input? A question about structuring the python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I am trying to implement the methodology described [here](https://medium.com/optuna/lightgbm-tuner-new-optuna-integration-for-hyperparameter-optimization-8b7095e99258). The details except for the ones I will post here are irrelevant to the scope of the question

1. The intent is to implement hyperparameter tuning for lightgbm
2. I do it the typical way - import lightgbm via `import lightgbm`, write a class that does it for me
3. There is a special way to do hyperparameter optimization for lightgbm and that requires me to import lightgbm like `from optuna.integration import lightgbm` and the rest of the code can remain identical
4. I want to provide the end users the capability to choose between the vanilla methodology (in point 2) or the special methodology (point 3). To implement that I have the following in the `__init__` of the main class and the `__init__` takes and argument `use_lightgbm_heuristics=True`

```
global lightgbm
    if use_lightgbm_heuristics:
        print("will be using heuristics")
        from optuna.integration import lightgbm
    else:
        print("will be using vanilla lgbm")
        import lightgbm
```

There is an import statement in the main class of my code. Can I do better?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, conditional imports like that is only really necessary if the subsequent import executes code that irrevocably change the original module, it would be useful to take a look at how the `optuna` package actually handles (or not) the `lightgbm` package first.

Viewing the [source](https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/v3.1.0/optuna/integration/lightgbm.py#L10-L12) for the package, you will find that it does in fact import `lightgbm` as part of the package, but without changing anything about it in the code that follows.

So given that fact, it's safe to actually import both packages as a unique local name, and then set `lightgbm` to whatever is desired.  This way will import both versions, and provide a method to switch between the `lightgbm` modules so the expected one active within your module.

```
import lightgbm as vanilla_lightgbm
from optuna.integration import lightgbm as optuna_lightgbm

def set_lightgbm_heuristics(use_lightgbm_heuristics):
    global lightgbm
    if use_lightgbm_heuristics:
        print("will be using heuristics")
        lightgbm = optuna_lightgbm
    else:
        print("will be using vanilla lgbm")
        lightgbm = vanilla_lightgbm

# this sets the default to use the optuna version
set_lightgbm_heuristics(True)

# code that uses lightgbm.${submodules} follows
```

Alternatively, if you make use of classes, the option to assign an instance of the module to an attribute of the class and provide a way for users to set that may also be a valid approach.  This may be safer, though without knowing the rest of your code or how your code is structured, I cannot make a specific recommendation here.

If you do support switching of implementation for end users, do take care that default values do not hard code to support one or the other, as calling the switch function may result in undesirable side effects.

Similarly, the approach to import both and then have a flag to switch between the two will grant the users of your library to use both versions at the same time, rather than being stuck with one version (either vanilla or the optuna modified version) at a time.

---

For completeness, in the event where the second module **does** make an irrevocable change to the original (e.g. replacing some attribute of the original), a re-import of the original should be triggered in the switching function.  However, this may not necessary remove all side-effects caused by the second module (it really shouldn't do that), so testing should be done to ensure that no unexpected behavior is caused by that.